# How to carry out multidimensional scaling on 12-nations data set reported by Wish (1971)

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I currently self-study multidimensional scaling. Amongst others, I study Borg & Groenen (2005): Modern multidimensional scaling : theory and applications.

On page 10, they present a real-life data set reported by Wish (1971). Wish (1971) asked 18 students to rate the global similarity of different pairs of nations such as France and China on a 9-point rating scale ranging from 1 = very different to 9 = very similar. Since the data set is publicly available, I wanted to replicate the  result in R for practice purposes. As a first step, I wanted to replicate the following configuration also presented in Borg & Groenen (2005, p. 10).

[image]

I proceeded as follows:

```
library(smacof)                       ### this package contains the data set
data(wish)                            ### that is the data set
```

Since the data sets contains similarity ratings, I applied non metric multidimensional scaling using the isoMDS command of the MASS package. Even though the textbook authors speak of a "two-dimensional MDS configuration", I also tried higher-dimensional solutions. I therefore coded a loop that carries out multidimensional scaling for configurations containing dimensions from 2 to 9.

```
X <- c()
for (i in 2:9) {
  MDS <- isoMDS(wish, k = i)
  X <- c(X, MDS$stress)
  plot(MDS$points[,c(1,2)])
  text(MDS$points[, 1], MDS$points[, 2], colnames(as.matrix(wish)), cex=.6, 
  pos = 1)
}
plot(X, type = "b")                    ### this  allowed me to plot the stress levels associated with each configuration
```

None of the resulting plots resembled the one presented in Borg & Groenen (2005, p. 10). For example, the map for 2 dimensions is as follows:

[image]

I checked that the data set is identical to the one reported by Borg & Groenen (2005, p. 10). I also tried out metric scaling as follows:

```
for (i in 2:9) {
  plot(smacofSym(wish, ndim=i))
}
```

Again, I was not able to replicate the results reported by Borg & Groenen (2005,p. 10). However, I am not sure if I made any mistake while trying to replicate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the base R `cmdscale`, I get a *similar* result to Borg & Groenen.

If you look at the structure of `wish` you will see that it is 
simply a vector of 66 numbers. I interpret this as the  lower triangluar
similarity matrix.  I convert this into a full dissimilarity matrix so that I 
can use `cmdscale` and plot. The positions roughly align with the positions
from Borg & Groenen.

```
library(smacof)
data(wish)

## Construct distance matrix
SM = matrix(0, nrow=12, ncol=12)
SM[lower.tri(SM)] = wish
SM = SM + t(SM)
diag(SM) = 9
DM = 9-SM

## MDS & plotting
MDS = cmdscale(DM)
plot(MDS, pch=20, xlim=c(-4,4), ylim=c(-4,4))
text(MDS, labels = attr(wish, "Labels"), adj=c(0.5,-0.6), cex=0.8)
abline(0.5,0.3, lty=2)
abline(-1,-3.8, lty=2)
```

[image: Plot of Multi-Dimensional Scaling]

Comment: I am a complete idiot. The Wish dataset contains similarity ratings. I therefore should have converted the dataset into dissimilarities. This is what you have done: ('DM = 9-SM' (see above)). Once I incorporated this step I managed to replicate the results as well.

Comment: If this is the worst mistake that you make in your life,  you  are a genius.

Comment: thanks. BTW, I have a follow-up questions. You may be interested in it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401881/multidimensional-scaling-how-to-determine-stress-per-point-in-r